# Cannot pass MediaStreamConstraints object to getUserMedia method

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, electron, screen-capture

I am making a desktop application with ElectronJs and Angualr 13. The application hasaand screen recording and sharing feature. The code below works on a simple electronJs application:

```
let constraints = {
        audio: false,
        video: {
            mandatory: {
                chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
                chromeMediaSourceId: displayId
            }
        }
    };

let stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
```

But when I used it in my angular ElectronJs/Angular 13 application  it throws the error below:

Argument of type '{ audio: boolean; video: { mandatory: { chromeMediaSource: string; chromeMediaSourceId: string; }; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MediaStreamConstraints'.
Types of property 'video' are incompatible.
Type '{ mandatory: { chromeMediaSource: string; chromeMediaSourceId: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'boolean |

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing the following line from :

```
let stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
```

To :

```
let stream = await (navigator.mediaDevices as any).getUserMedia(constraints);
```